# phpDocumentor tab delimiter

Tags: php, phpdoc

Pretty simple one: is it ok to use tabs inside phpDocumentor tags? Like:

```
/**
 * @param string @some_var        Description
 */
```

- There's a tab between @some_var and Description

Didn't find anything against tabs (except list declaration), but I just want to make sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears at one point there was an issue with it using tabs but it has since been [fixed](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/issues/380) almost a year ago. So yes, you are safe to use tabs as the regex used to match them will account for them.

Comment: Thanks! Found that bug myself, but couldn't find anything else on the issue.